# Which one is correct: 'listening', 'listen' or 'to listen'?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which of these is correct?

1. The only thing you could do was **listening**
2. The only thing you could do was **listen**
3. The only thing you could do was **to listen**

Or do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**listening** is a noun (a gerund is a noun) and does not make sense here; you need a verb (because you were *doing* the only thing you could).

I would strongly prefer the bare infinitive **listen** but I do not believe that using the full infinitive **to listen** would be wrong, necessarily. It would sound a little awkward and perhaps old-fashioned.